# why am I getting a horizontal solid strip when projecting large image?

Tags: coordinate-system, tiles, mapnik

I am using Mapnik to create tiles on a tile server.  I'm depicting sea level rise in North America using SRTM data, and it works fine in most of the continent.  However, when zoomed out in my browser (zoom levels 5 and lower), I get a peculiar horizontal stripe across the entire continent:

[image: horizontal stripe across north america]

When I am zoomed farther in, this stripe does not appear, which makes me think it's not an issue with the data itself.  The stripe is from 51 degrees N to 52N.  I suspect it's some sort of projection issue, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

Mapnik is being used with Tirex; it is reading from a .vrt file which in turn references ~2400 tifs.

Comment: It looks like a pyramid issue if it's only at particular scale. What format is your SRTM in? You said VRT, but what are the tiles (TIFF, but GeoTiff, world Tiff, compression...)?

Comment: They are GeoTiffs that I created with LZW compression using gdal_calc.py.  I have not created any pyramids or raster overviews.

Comment: The tile cache (if present) should have overviews, it could help to regenerate the tile cache or build the pyramids using *GDALADDO -ro <name and path of vrt> 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256* to avoid having to resample so much on-the-fly.

Comment: It's a brand new tile cache (I deleted what was there previously to test).  I will read about gdaladdo...

Comment: If that doesn't help then perhaps uncompress some of the likely problem tiles. If you can track down the (likely) bad tile, or at least short list it to a half-dozen or so, then convert to GeoTiff uncompressed with GDAL_Translate then rename and replace the tiles keeping the same names you will not need to rebuild the VRT (names, projection and extent all being the same). This technique has helped me previously with a VRT with a bad tile (with very little data in it) LZW compressed... it seems the decompressor tripped up at certain zoom scales so by pre-uncompressing it fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Michael.  I haven't yet created overviews, but I wanted to add that when I use a VRT that references the original .hgt files that I downloaded (instead of the GeoTiffs I created from them), I get the very same issue.  So while that doesn't rule out compression issues, it (perhaps?) reduces their likelihood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may be interested:  the problem seems to have been that my .vrt had coordinates that spanned across the -180 longitude.  Left was a pixel or two beyond the line (-180.00004) and right was ~0 degrees).  Clipping it seems to have solved the problem.